# TDE In marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, encryption, transparent-data-encryption

I have been researching TDE(as my understanding is that FLE is going away) for Marketing Cloud, and came across this [Link](https://www.devsutd.com/securing-data-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud-part-three-of-three/). It mentions "TDE within the Marketing Cloud environment requires a dedicated database. Existing customers on a multi-tenant database need to migrate to a single-tenant database to implement TDE."  Is this true?  I am looking at this [Stack Exchange Question/Answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261060/has-anyone-enabled-transparent-data-encryption-tde-in-marketing-cloud), and it mentions getting a new MID.  Is getting a new MID the process of going from Multi Tenant to a Single Tenant Database?  Any information about this process would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the TDE is at DB level, it can't be either or when you share a DB with other environments - as some of them would need TDE, others would not. So the only option here is to move to a new shared DB which has TDE enabled - for all tenants. This operation is indeed also a DB migration, since the content of your old DB needs to be replicated to the new TDE enabled instance - so do expect some downtime while data is moved. As this is a different instance, your MID(s) will also change. I am not into all the specific details, as I am yet to experience such a migration first hand.

Comment: is this still the case? I've worked on an account on a shared DB and the MID did not change. Would this simply mean that it was already on a DB that had TDE enabled? And if on a shared DB, would all tenants share the same key?

Comment: @AntonioDePalma - I suspect that all the tenants on a shared DB with TDE share the same key. This is due to the fact, that you can't bring your own key, as you normally can on a dedicated DB with TDE.